# Summation of geometric progression proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, proof-explanation

I'm not sure if we're allowed to add pictures here, but I can't understand how they got the line where I highlighted in the proof.

If I understand correctly, they are somehow breaking up the summation of $n+1$ into summation of $n$ and $n+1$ term?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} ar^k \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^k + ar^{n+1}  \text{( remove $(n+1)$-th term from summation)}\\
&=\left(ar^0+\sum_{k=1}^{n} ar^k\right) + ar^{n+1} -ar^0 \text{(add and remove same term)}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} ar^k\right) + ar^{n+1} -a\\
\end{align}